# SQL Insert ,Update using Merge Store Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, bulkinsert

I need to do a bulk `Insert` and/or `Update` for a target table in a SQL database. I have already tried the Merge stored procedure. In the target table I have a composite key.

I need to generate a pattern for first field (of the key) while inserting. I have tried a user-defined function that returns a pattern key which is unique for each of the rows.

My question is, how do I incorporate this function into a query that would auto-generate the key and insert the respective fields for each record?

TargetTable is my destination table in database and it has two columns - `Key1(Bigint)`,`Key2(int)`. Once again, this is a composite key.

**Note:** I only want to generate the key for the first field/column.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
Merge Targettable as T  
Using SourceTable as s  
ON s.Key1 = T.Key1 and  
s.Key2=T.Key2  
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE  
SET T.UserName = S.UserName  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
INSERT (Key1, Key2, UserName)  
VALUES (dbo.UserDefiendFunction(@parama1),Key2,userName)
```

`UserDefinedFunction` returns the pattern i want. 
Here's my User Defined Function:

```
Create function [dbo].[UserDefinedFunction] (  
@Param1 int)  
returns BIGINT   
AS Begin  
DECLARE @ResultVar BIGINT  
SET @ResultVar=CONVERT(BIGINT, (SELECT Cast(@Param1 AS VARCHAR(10))  
+ '' + Format((SELECT Count(userName)+1 FROM [dbo].[TableName]), '0')) )  
RETURN @ResultVar  
END
```

Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `using sourcetable as s`, use `using (select col1, col2, dbo.UserDefiendFunction(@parama1) as pattern from sourcetable) as s`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i have tried with your approach ..User defined function returns the same pattern for all the rows which i am inserting..the reason is userdefined function is called only once ...it will violate the primary key constraint during insertion...It Won't work..

Comment: Are you saying that for two calls to the UDF with the same value of @parama1 you'll always get different values, and you'll never get the same value twice?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid here we are using User defined function inside a merge store procedure.Merge Store Procedure scans all bulk values only once..hence user defined function is called only once..it is never called twice.it will give same pattern for all rows..during bulk insertion i need different pattern for each row..

Comment: Can you please post the code of your UDF?

Comment: @TabAlleman i have added the code of user defined function in my question..

Comment: Your UDF is a convoluted method of storing a human-formatted primary key in the table. This is a bad idea for many reasons. Just use an identity then update the table afterward with your human readable key.

Comment: I see now what you're trying to do with the UDF, and I agree with Nick.  There might be ways to do what you're trying to do with ROW_NUMBER(), but they are probably equally bad ideas.   If rows get deleted, you could end up with duplicate keys because the count of rows in the table will go down.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 join table 2 on Column1='SomeValue')
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
insert into ods..Table1 (Columname)
select [DatabaseName].[dbo].[UserDefinedFunction] (@paramater) as ColumnName
```

Comment: As Merge Store Procedure scans all values only once ..hence User Defined Function  called only once ..Pattern will be same for all rows which i am inserting...I need different pattern for each row.....